# Prove that a small shift in the diagonal term leads to smaller spectral radius (for Perron-Frobenius theorem)

Tags: matrices, spectral-theory

On Wikipedia, the proof for Perron Frobenius theorem in the strictly positive case has a confusing step: Suppose $T=A^m-\epsilon I$, where $\epsilon$ is smaller than the smallest diagonal term of strictly positive matrix $A^m$. Then it straightforwardly claim that $\rho(T)\le\rho(A^m)$. How can one prove this step?

Answer (score -1):

Eigenvalues of the matrix $A^m$ are also the roots of the polynomial equation
$$\det(A^m-\lambda I)=0$$
Thus $\lambda$ (roots of the above equation) are also eigenvalues of $A^m$. Now, note that
$$\det(A^m-\lambda I) = \det (\,\,(A^m-\epsilon I)-(\lambda-\epsilon) I\,\,)=\det (T-(\lambda - \epsilon)I)$$
Thus, following earlier argument, $\lambda - \epsilon$ should be the eigenvalues of $T$. Now, note that $$\rho(A^m)=\max_{i}|\lambda_i|$$
$$\rho(T)=\max_{i}|\lambda_i-\epsilon|$$
Now, note that 
$$\lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_n = T_{11}+\dots + T_{nn}$$ and also $T_{ii} > 0$. Let $T_{nn}$ be the smallest diagonal entry (w.l.o.g). This implies that $$\rho(A^m)= \max_{i}|\lambda_i|\geq \max_{i}|\lambda_i| - T_{nn}\geq \max_{i}|\lambda_i| - \epsilon \geq \rho(T)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this just claims that eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^m$ has a one-to-one correspondence to that of $T$, which is $\lambda-\epsilon$. So what happens to spectral radius?

Comment: Since the matrix is strictly positive, existence of the perron root, or a single positive eigenvalue which will also be the spectral radius is guaranteed. So for $T$, this will be reduced by $\epsilon$ which means the spectral radius is also reduced.

Comment: Your argument is circular. I am stuck on the same step and the issue is that you are citing the very theorem that the step is part of.

Comment: @Displayname I have updated the answer.

Comment: In the last step, the triangle inequality is pointing the wrong way. If it helps fix the problem, $\epsilon$ was chosen to be $A_{nn}/2$ (half the smallest diagonal entry of $A$), so the 2nd to last step is an equality.

Comment: Also, you're missing a factor of $\epsilon n$ in the trace equation, which doesn't seem to be used anywhere.